# Can I set a field value as object key in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, projection

I have a list of documents that looks like this:

```
_id: ObjectId('63c6a4b858612f44f37d4771')
type: "TypeA"
priority: 1

_id: ObjectId('627279d3ba7aef5d6418c867')
type: "TypeB"
priority: 2
```

The type here is unique so I can't have two documents with the same type. Now I want to set the **type** as the object name, with **_id** and **priority** inside the object. Like this:

```
TypeA: {
    _id: ObjectId('63c6a4b858612f44f37d4771'),
    priority: 1
}

TypeB: {
    _id: ObjectId('627279d3ba7aef5d6418c867'),
    priority: 2
}
```

I've tried something like this:

```
{
    $project: {
        '$$this.type': {
            _id: '$_id',
            priority: '$priority'
        }
    }
}
```

I just need help with getting the value of **type** as the object key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a dynamic field name, create the object as an array of `k` `v` pairs, and use `$arrayToObject` like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      newDoc: [ {k:"$type", v: {_id:"$_id", priority: "$priority"}} ]
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$arrayToObject: "$newDoc"}}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ckMUkR5wgR6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$group` aggregation operator in combination with the `$addToSet` operator to group the documents by the `type` field, and create an array of objects for each "type" group that contains the `_id` and `priority` fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group:
         {
           _id: "$type",
           documents: { $push: { _id: "$_id", priority: "$priority" } }
         }
   }
])
```

This will create a new array of objects for each unique `type` field, where the `type` field is the key of the object and the `documents` array contains the `_id` and `priority` fields